# How to call a function on scroll of ajax loaded element using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

How to call a function on scroll of ajax loaded element using jquery.
This code work properly. But after element load through ajax code not working.
this element "ElementNameHere[]" is loading through ajax.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[name="ElementNameHere[]"]').bind('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
            alert("<name> = "+this.innerHTML);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebind your even once element is loaded after ajax call.

For an example,

```
$.ajax({
  url: "MyUrl.php",
}).done(function() {

    //your code to append new Html Elements

    //Rebind only newly appended elements again here.
    $('[name="ElementNameHere[]"]').bind('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
            alert("<name> = "+this.innerHTML);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Sorry but can you please give me a demo how to rebind new html elements?

Comment: You can use exactly same code snippet but just change jquery selector to point to newly created element.

Comment: all element have same name & i have to select them by name this is the name of all element "ElementNameHere[]"  Now what i have to do ?

Comment: if you just added those elements in `done` function you might be holding reference to those elements there you could just write `newElements.bind('scroll',...`. If you can give me a jsfiddle link, I can alter your script.

Comment: i will give you link in tommorrow at nw i am not near to my pc. i am in office. thanks you

Comment: This is link bro. On scroll comment of first & second post a message alert means its working. but after load any post via ajax(via scroll down page) message will not alert on scroll comments http://topcollegesindia.in/brijesh

Answer (score 0):

I have used infinite ajax scroll jquery plugin in the past and it has worked with the Email Interface very well. This will look after for pagination, calculating when to call.

it will also show loading... text if you require so.

It is easy to use too:

http://plugins.jquery.com/ias/

http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/getting-started.html